# reset Answer function

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have figured out how to reset all the radio buttons, but how can I reset the message that shows after the correct answer is given?
some help pls

HTML

```html
<button id="resetButton" type="button" onclick="resetAns()">Reset Answer !</button>
```

JS

```
function resetAns() {
  this.checkAnswers()
  for (var i = 1; i <= totalQCount; i++) {
    if ($("input[name='Q" + i + "']:checked")) {
      $("input[name='Q" + i + "']").prop('checked', false)
    }
  }
}

function checkAnswers() {
  for (var i = 1; i <= totalQCount; i++) {
    var qObj = lstQuestions[i - 1]
    var radioValue = $("input[name='Q" + i + "']:checked").val()
    if (radioValue) {
      var resultDivId = 'result' + i + 'Div'
      $('#' + resultDivId).html('correct answerr is ' + qObj.correct_answer.fontcolor('green'))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: do you want to reset message when you call `resetAns()`? in which div you want to reset message?

Answer (score 1):

Add this under `resetAns` function

```
$("#" + resultDivId).html('')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
function resetAns() {
  this.checkAnswers();
  for (var i = 1; i <= totalQCount; i++) {
    if ($("input[name='Q" + i + "']:checked")) {
      $("input[name='Q" + i + "']").prop("checked", false);
      var resultDivId = "result" + i + "Div";
      $("#" + resultDivId).html('')
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see we're clearing the content of div using `$("#" + resultDivId).html('')`